# change bootstrap navbar collapse breakpoint

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap navbar currently collapses at 786px I want it to collapse at 876px. I've tried adding this to my css file but it doesn't seem to be working since nothing changes.

```
@media (min-width: 876px){
   .navbar-collapse {
       display: none !important;
   }
}
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. In the [Grid system](http://www.getbootstrap.sk/customize/#grid-system) set the field `@grid-float-breakpoint` value of `876`.
2. Click the `Compile and Download` button at the bottom of the page.
3. Extract the files `bootstrap.css` and  `bootstrap.min.css` from the resulting archive.
4. Use them instead of the standard files `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` on your site.